# Prevent change state (page) in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this page (app.photo) with the user could upload and view photos.

Clicking view button call this function:

```
$scope.delPhoto = function(IDphoto,name) {
    $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Elimino la foto...', duration:500});
    $http.post('http://www.digitalxp.it/public/speedjob/del_img.asp?nome='+name).success(function(data, status, headers){
        alert("foto eliminata");
        $state.go('app.profilo');
        $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://www.digitalxp.it/public/speedjob/upjob.php?nome=Amministratore'}).success(function(data){
            $scope.photos = data;
        }).error(function(){
            alert("error");
        });
        }).error(function(){
            alert("Foto non eliminata!")});
    return false
}
```

My problem is that when the function succeeds, the page change (go automatically to app.welcome), so I add `$state.go('app.profilo')` but this cause a bad effect (first go to app.welcome and than to app.photo).

Is it possible only to refresh the view app.photo?

Comment: How does it go to app.welcome? Is the delPhoto event called from an anchor tag or something?

Comment: it's called by this:
<div ng-repeat="photo in photos" class="home-sq">
      <div><a href="#" ng-hold="delPhoto($index, photo.name)"><img ng-src="{{photo.file}}" /></a></div>
    </div>

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved.... i make ng-click (or on-hold it's same) in a href! I'm so stupid!
But now I've another problem... After success I would go to tab inside view.
This is my page code:

```
<ion-view title="PROFILO" ng-controller="loadProfilo">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left" >
    <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-nav-buttons side="right" >
    <button menu-toggle="right" class="button button-icon icon ion-chatbubbles"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-tabs tabs-type="tabs-icon-only" class="tabs-icon-top tabs-dark">
    <ion-tab title="I MIEI DATI" icon-on="ion-person-add" icon-off="ion-person">
      <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">
        <h2>I MIEI DATI</h2>
        <div class="list card">
          <div class="item item-avatar"> <img ng-src="http://www.digitalxp.it/public/speedjob/users/Amministratore/{{profilo.photo_url}}">
            <h1>{{profilo.name}} </h1>
            <p>{{profilo.anni}} anni</p>
          </div>
          <div class="item item-body">
            <p>Nome: <b>{{profilo.nome}}</b></p>
            <p>Cognome: <b>{{profilo.cognome}}</b></p>
            <p>Città: {{profilo.city}} <b>({{profilo.provincia}})</b></p>
            <p> {{profilo.desc}} </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="FOTO" icon-on="ion-social-instagram" icon-off="ion-social-instagram-outline">
      <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true" ng-controller="CameraCtrl">
        <h2>METTICI LA FACCIA</h2>
        <p>Scegli una foto oppure scattane subito una per farti conoscere dagli utenti della Community!</p>
        <div class="button-bar"> <a class="button" ng-click="takePicture();">Scatta</a> <a class="button" ng-click="selectPicture();">Scegli</a> <a class="button" ng-click="viewPictures();">Vedi</a> </div>
        <div ng-show="picData" class="item item-image"><img id="myImage" class="item" ng-src="{{picData}}" ng-click="uploadPicture();" style="height:200px;"/></div>
        <div class="home-sq">
          <div ng-repeat="photo in photos" ng-click="setPhoto($index, photo.name, profilo.user_id)" on-hold="delPhoto($index, photo.name)" style="background-image:url({{photo.file}});background-size:120% auto"> </div>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="ABILITA'" icon-on="ion-ios7-cog" icon-off="ion-ios7-cog-outline">
      <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">
        <h2>LE MIE ABILITA'</h2>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-tab>
  </ion-tabs>
</ion-view>
```

When I call the ng-click"setPhoto()" I'm on tab named "FOTO". I would go, after success setPhoto, to tab named "I MIEI DATI".
Is it possible?

Comment: How did you stop change state?